# mail error with PHP Mailer

Tags: php

As advised I have tried using PHP Mailer to send email attachments with a form, however I keep getting the error message "Mailer Error: Could not instantiate mail function.

I have rechecked the email address and cannot find any error for same

here is the code for the PHP as well as the code for the form. Any input is greatly appreciated. Thanks, JB

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHPMailer - Mail() basic test</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

$body             = file_get_contents('talent3.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->AddReplyTo("jbgraphics@rogers.com","First Last");

$mail->SetFrom('jbgraphics@rogers.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("jbgraphics@rogers.com","First Last");

$address = "jbgraphics@rogers.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Beadle");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), basic";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; //     optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.pdf");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.jpeg"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Message sent!";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

and the form code:

```
<form action="test_mail_basic.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file" class="bodyCopy"><span class="bodyCopy">Attach resume:</span></label><br     />
<input type="file" name="attach1" id="file" /><br /> 
<br />
<label for="file" class="bodyCopy"><span class="bodyCopy">Attach photo:</span></label><br />
<input type="file" name="attach2" id="file" /><br /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is a result of the php [mail()](http://php.net/mail) function returning false.

Typically, it returns false if sendmail is not configured correctly in php.ini or if sendmail doesn't exist on the server.

Are you running this on a Linux server or Windows?  A very simple test to see if mail is working is to run this code:

```
<?php
$to = 'you@yoursite.com';

$res = mail($to, 'Testing mail', "This is a test\n\nEnd.", "From: $to");

if ($res) {
    echo "Message appears to have been accepted"; // does not mean it will be delivered
} else {
    echo "PHP mail() failed.";
}
```

If you are on Windows, you will likely need to use an SMTP server instead of php mail() so you will need to use SMTP as seen in this [phpmailer SMTP example](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/source/browse/trunk/examples/test_smtp_basic.php).

If you are on shared hosting, it may be that the message is being rejected because of some of the extra parameters being send to the mail function.

Comment: you create a file with this code inside and just run it on local host. You need to have apache, php and postfix/exim in order for it to work

Comment: Do I save the code as a .php file or an .html file? Also, how do I run this – I still don't understand that part. By running, do you mean uploading to the server and then opening it in a browser?

Comment: Just save it with any name with a `.php` extension.  You can run it by just accessing the URL in your browser.

Comment: Got it and tested it Message came back as"Message appears to have been accepted" so its safe to assume that mail is working.

Comment: Yeah if you got the message that's an even better sign.  Now try changing the `mail()` call to look like this: `mail($to, 'Testing mail', "This is a test\n\nEnd.", "From: $to", "-oi -f $to");` and see if it fails.

Comment: Tried that and got the following message:
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The fifth parameter is disabled in SAFE MODE in /home/castmeb1/public_html/test.php on line 5
PHP mail() failed.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere!  If you see line [787 of class.phpmailer.php](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/source/browse/trunk/class.phpmailer.php#787) you will see it attempts to use the 5th paramter `$params` which was set to "-oi %SENDER_ADDRESS%".  Since safe mode is in effect, it is blocking that from working.  I don't see any way to bypass this in phpmailer.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately we got somewhere in the wrong direction.  If your host gives you SMTP access for your mail accounts, you could use the SMTP example and should have no problems.